# How to prevent a spring app running multiple times?

Tags: java, spring

How can I prevent a simple spring app to be launched multiple times on a pc?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

The user should not be able to start the jar twice if one is still running.

Comment: You cannot launch it twice, the second one will fail as generally the ports are already in use (assuming it it as web application).

Comment: It isn't a web application...

Comment: Then add the `ApplicationPidFileWriter` which writes a file at startup. In your main you can check if that file exists (before calling `SpringApplication.run`) and do whatever you like. You cold read it and see if the proces is really active, if so remove the file and start the app or just start it, blow up etc. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-process-monitoring.html

Answer (score -1):

Create a property after the start (In MyApp) and check if the file exists. When it is existing dont call this line:

```
 SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
```

When the application terminates delete the property.

Comment: What if the application was terminated and the file wasn't removed?

Comment: You can do this: file.deleteOnExit(); It is no problem. Thanks for downvote :D

Comment: I mean that it might be the case that `java` process is killed by the system and you'll not be able to delete the file programatically. In that case the file will block the app to start.

Comment: Then you have to delete the file. If you (or system) kill(s) the process, there is no recovery for it. Best practice is not to double click on JARs in production.